# Set elements height to var and display

Tags: javascript, jquery, height

I have this code which I think is pretty straight forward:

```
$(function() {
    $(".box").click(function(){
        var origSize =  $(this).height;
        console.log (origSize);
    });
});
```

But I just get `function()` appearing in my console. I'm not sure whats gone wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var origSize =  $(this).height;
```

Should be:

```
var origSize =  $(this).height();
```

Read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/height/), `height` is a function, not a property.

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out, you're using the `height()` method as a property. You should consider using `outerHeight()` instead to get a more accurate value that accounts for padding and border widths.